# Value generator for regexp

Tags: regex

I have some regular expression, for example: "/[0-9]{3}/"
I need values generator for this regular expression.

```
regexp = "/[0-9]{3}/"
value_generator(regexp, 5) # 5 is count of values.
```

I want to output a list of
324
533
654
444
546

It is possible?

Comment: You want a random number generator or one to match any given regex? Also what language?

Comment: Are there any limits on what regular expressions are allowed? Can they be arbitrarily long and complex? Can advanced non-regular features be used such as backreferences or recursive regular espressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just random data matching the regexp?

Just generate infinite amounts of random strings, select those which by chance happen to match your regexp and output those matches.

Comment: It turns out that the search for a regular expression match is irreversible?
Thank you.

Comment: @СергейБлохин: It depends on what regular expressions you allow. If you allow an advanced, arbitrarily complex, non-regular (possibly even Turing complete) regular expression syntax then it's impossible. For a simplified regular expression language with limited features then it's possible. For the example you posted it's trivial.